# Using create-react-app and connecting it to my git repository?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Apologize up front as I am super new to React. I run the command npx create-react-app {test-app} and I understand that it creates a git repository for me. My confusion is I don't understand how I connect my github page to that repository. (if that makes sense) [connect my newly created GitHub repo page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDtxi.png) connected to [React project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rJ3Q.png)  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Github repository. Then copy the link to clone the repository.
Next you can head towards the react project folder and open the terminal.

Run
`git remote add origin <url_you_copied>`.
After that you can do, add commit push operations.

Answer (score 2):

Run the below commands:

```
git init
git remote add origin <url you copied>
```

`git init` initializes a local git repo.
`git remote add origin <url you copied>` is just what repo to push the code to.

Then, to push a commit:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git push origin main
```

Answer (score 1):

create empty repository in github account then
create react app then
open react app project in visual studio code then
open terminal in visual studio code then write

```
git init  
git remote add origin (url your project you can see url in repository github you created first time)  
git add .  
git commit -m "commit message"  
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Hey Mahmood Masoud, thank you so much for the answer! I figured it out but hopefully your comment helps someone else. Appreciate the response to my super green question!

Comment: This exact answer was already provided above, wasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to install GitHub application on your system; In command prompt, you need to go to the location of your React App and type '_Projectname_git init

Then open GitHub desktop application and give the path of the project to upload. Then publish it by giving name of it and commit it.

Automatically it will connected your GitHub page. You can find the added repositories.

*You must sign in to your GitHub account on desktop GitHub application before doing this process